# ParquetFileReader leading to too many TCP connections in CLOSE_WAIT state

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, parquet, parquet-mr

I am trying to read meta data info from a parquet file :

```
metaData=ParquetFileReader.readFooter(fs.getConf(),file) ;
```

This line opens a connection in `CLOSE_WAIT` -state (checked using `lsof -p pid` command).

```
TCP rack162-hdp26-dev:36608->rack162-hdp26-dev:1019 (CLOSE_WAIT)
```

On more than 65,536 files it returns a "too many open files" -error (hence requires to restart my application). I tried replacing by :

```
try (ParquetFileReader r = ParquetFileReader.open(fs.getConf(), file)) {

     logger.info("Getting metadata for:" + file.toString());
     metaData = r.getFooter()

     //other code//
}
```

but still facing an issue. I already tried a parquet-hadoop jar of version 1.8.1, 1.10.1, 1.11.1 but facing issues with each.

Comment: What if you do `r.close()` in the loop?

Comment: We have tried this, but it didn't work. Although we are using this in try with resources block. So it is closed by try itself

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue? I am running into the same issue of "Too many open files"